# Loading large images

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, android-glide

Nowadays, images which are captured by phones camera are too large.

I was asking how to load images that its size is too large ( > 5 MB ) into `ImageView`

after a long search I found libs like `Picasso` & `Glide` and I decided to use Glide as following

```
Glide.with(this)
       .asBitmap()
       .load(mPath)
       .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
               // use loaded bitmap here    
           }     
});
```

and it works well but, in case of image size is big to start from 4 MB and above it takes a too long time loading the image although it is loaded from local storage.

so my question is how to deal with large images like that?

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance you need to reduce file size. So please use any compression technique to compress file then use glide library to set in imageview.

Use below link for reference:
[See more](http://mindbowser.com/image-compression-in-android/)

Comment: but, compress reduces image quality

Comment: According to screen size we don't need high quality image. Compressed size is enough for UI rendering.

Comment: but, lower images size ( bad quality ) will get worst?

Comment: There is no change in physical image. For rendering purpose only we are going to compress. So it will not affect original size of the file.

Comment: I won't need to use glide anymore right? also, please tell me which method do the compress part as I'm new

Comment: Use this library for compression https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Set images normally. No need to use glide library.

Comment: the same issue takes a long time with images of 12mb size -_-